# What are some bounds on $\displaystyle \sum_{n\leq N} \mu(n)e(\alpha n)$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

As usual, let $e(x):=2\pi i x$. I already know of a bound on $\sum_{n\leq N}\mu(n)$: by the prime number theorem, it is $\ll x\exp(-c(\log x)^{\frac{1}{2}})$ for some $c>0$.

> However, what happens when we consider the sum $\displaystyle \sum_{n\leq N} \mu(n)e(\alpha n)$?

I could imagine using partial summation to obtain a leading term which is $\ll N\exp(-c\sqrt{\log N})$using the prime number theorem, but I don't know how good a bound optimising $O(|\alpha|\int_1^N t\exp(-c\sqrt{\log t})\mathrm{d}t)$ would give me. Surely, there are some already available bounds? Thanks!

P.S. I am looking for bounds without assuming GRH.

Follow-up question: Is the circle-method somehow useful in this context?

Comment: See https://academic.oup.com/jlms/article-abstract/s2-43/2/193/862020?redirectedFrom=PDF and references within

Comment: This question swas asked before: https://mathoverflow.net/q/378685

Comment: Yes, thank you. That is precisely what I was looking for. Thanks for the link to the Baker and Harman paper too.